# Importing celery task within Django view

Tags: python, django, celery

I am trying to execute a celery task that among other things, communicates with a specific Django view with a pipe.

I have been trying all day to import the celery tasks file (tasks.py) from the Django views (views.py) without any success.

I have also checked the file permissions but this was not the case.

I have added to sys.path the path of the file desired to import (tasks.py), and then import it, but I keep getting an ImportError. However, when trying to import another script on the same folder (script1), the import succeeds.

**views.py**

```
...
sys.path.append('/home/celery')
import script1 #SUCCEEDS
# Trying to import "/home/celery/tasks.py" here
import tasks #FAILS
...
```

**tasks.py**

```
...
@app.task
def start_operation(client,**kwargs):
  # Pipe comes here
...
```

The celery directory structure is the following:

```
/home
├── celery
    ├── script1.py
        tasks.py
```

And the Django proyect directory structure:

```
/myapp
├── myapp
    ├── views.py
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you creating celery task outside django project? You can try this https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ tutorial. Its quite simple and easy to follow

Comment: Could you provide the entire error traceback? My suspicion is that your `ImportError` is ultimately originating from a failed import *within* `tasks.py`.